# Vue JS Dynamic Router No Response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

I want to use the router dynamically. I installed the babel-dynamic-import plug-in. I don't get any errors, but when it switches to the page, it can't render the component.

```js
async function loadView(view) {
  return () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "view-[request]" */ `@/views/${view}`).then(view => view);
}

function parseSystemTree(item) {
  let nav = []
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    
    if (item[key].link !== '') {
      let navData = {
        path: item[key].link,
        name: item[key].name,
        meta: {title: item[key].name},
        component: loadView(item[key].view.toString()), /* import('@/views/Settings/UserOperations/AddNewUser.vue') */
        children: Object.keys(item[key].child).length > 0 ? parseSystemTree(item[key].child) : []
      }

      nav.push(navData)
    }
  })
  return nav
}

var navigations = []

if (typeof localStorage.getItem('system_tree') !== 'object') {
  const systemTree = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('system_tree'))
  navigations = parseSystemTree(systemTree)
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  // routes
  routes: routes.concat(navigations)
})
```

Comment: FYI, `.then(view => view)` is totally redundant

Comment: yes I removed that part